# NSTimer and code for reset button in xCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Ok, I'm trying to create a reset button that resets everything to the original state (ex: score, grade, etc.) when it's hit. This app also works with `NSTimer`. However, every time the reset button is hit, the timer goes faster each time. This is my code:

```
int count;
- (void)updateUI:(NSTimer *)timer {
    count++;
    if (count <=10)
        self.progressView.progress = (float)count/10.0f;
    else {
        [self.myTimer invalidate];
        self.myTimer = nil;
   }
}

- (void) resetTimer {
        count = 0;
        self.myTimer = 
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(updateUI:) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];
}
```

(the `self.myTimer`... is called in `viewDidLoad` method)

Please help me to correct the mistake.

Comment: paste code from viewDidLoad, please. And please specify or paste snippet of code when `-resetTimer` method is called. I think that timer is faster each time because it's created many times. But need more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Stonz2 said

```
- (void) resetTimer {
    count = 0;
    [[self myTimer] invalidate];
    [self setMyTimer:nil]; 
    [self setMyTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval 
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(updateUI:) 
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:YES]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. I'm now done with my very first game. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You need to invalidate the existing timer when you reset. The reason it's going faster is because you're calling `updateUI` twice as often when you hit the `resetTimer` button again. Invalidate it before you schedule a new timer.

Comment: More specifically, the old timer(s) aren't being deallocated; they're still around and still firing, because they're retained by the run loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I just googled about what you said. I now understand more. You guys are great!

Answer (score -2):

you are using the "interval"-variable to set the interval. Did you try doing it with a fixed value?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. There is a problem like @Stonz2 mentioned.

Comment: I use interval as variable for some reason. I actually tried it with a constant but it didn't work. Stonz2 and ColdLogic helped me to solve this problem. Thank you for your help too :)